# 'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type' Error after adding new dependency injection to already implemented & unit tested class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, junit5

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.companyname.enterpriseteam.demo.anonymizer.DAnonymizer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here is a mock but logically accurate representation of the code

Config Package

```
…
import org.companyname.enterpriseteam.demo.anonymizer.DAnonymizer;
import org.companyname.entuserfilter.externals.adminusersearch.AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer;
…


@Configuration
public class AdminUserSearchAnonymizationConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer
      adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer(final DAnonymizer dAnonymizer) {
    return new adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizerImpl(dAnonymizer);
  }
}
```

New interface I created in a different package

```
…
Some imports
…

public interface AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer {
  List<StoredUserRecord> anonymizeAdminSearchUserRecordsIfNeeded(
      final List<StoredUserRecord> storedUserRecords,
      final String orgId,
      @Nullable final Long requestUserId);
}
```

The interface’s implementation

```
…
Some imports
…


public class AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizerImpl
    implements AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer {
  private final DAnonymizer dAnonymizer;

  public AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizerImpl(final DAnonymizer dAnonymizer) {
    this.dAnonymizer = dAnonymizer;
  }


  @Override
  public List<StoredUserRecord> anonymizeAdminSearchUserRecordsIfNeeded(
      final List<StoredUserRecord> storedUserRecords,
      final String orgId,
      @Nullable final Long requestUserId) {
    if (!DConstants.COMPANY_ORG_ID.equals(orgId) || requestUserId == null) {
      // System.out.println("NO ANONYMIZATION" + storedUserRecords);
      return storedUserRecords;
    }

    // System.out.println("ANONYMIZATION TO BE DONE ON USER RECORDS LIST" + storedUserRecords);
    return storedUserRecords.stream()
        .map(entry -> anonymizeUserRecordIfNeeded(entry, orgId, requestUserId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }


  private StoredUserRecord anonymizeUserRecordIfNeeded(
      final StoredUserRecord storedUserRecord, final String orgId, final Long requestUserId) {
        final var anonymizedStoredUserRecord =
        dAnonymizer.getAnonymizedUserInfoForOrg(
            orgId, storedUserRecord.userId().get(), requestUserId);

        return anonymizedStoredUserRecord
        .map(
            anon ->
                new StoredUserRecord(
                    storedUserRecord.userId(),
                    anon.email(),
                    storedUserRecord.externalId(),
                    anon.name(),
        .orElse(storedUserRecord);
  }
}
```

Constructor of class where dependency injection is performed

```
…
Some imports
…

public class AdminViewElasticSearchManager implements AdminViewManager {
  private final someObject1;
  private final someObject2;
  private final someObject3;
  private final someObject4;
  private final AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer
        adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer;

public AdminViewElasticSearchManager(
    someClass1 someObject1,
    someClass2 someObject2,
    someClass3 someObject3,
    someClass4 someObject4,
    AdminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer
        adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer
    ) {
  this.elasticSearchReader = elasticSearchReader;
  this.someObject1 = someObject1;
  this.someObject2 = someObject2;
  this.someObject3 = someObject3;
  this.someObject4 = someObject4;
  this.adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer =
          adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer;

}
```

Me using my new implementation’s method somewhere in that same class above

```
@Override
public UserRecordsWithPagination searchWithFilterParams(filterParams, pageRequest, requestUser) {
…
Some code
…

storedUserRecords =
this.adminSearchUserRecordsAnonymizer.anonymizeAdminSearchUserRecordsIfNeeded(
           storedUserRecords, filterParams.orgId, requestUser);
…
More code
…

}
```

Many tests are failing due to dependency injection issues and because of it, I can’t test properly.
This particular test is also not asserting like it should meaning my new class isn’t returning the proper list to its caller.
I wonder if its related to dependencies not being injected properly?

```
…
var filterParams =
    FilterParams.newBuilder()
        .setOrganizationId(UserRecordFixtures.MEMBER_USER_RECORD.organizationId())
        .setSearchNameOrEmails(List.of("johndoe"))
        .build();

var pageRequest =
    PageRequest.newBuilder()
        .setStart(Int64Value.of(0))
        .setLimit(Int64Value.of(1))
        .build();

var result = this.manager.queryByFilterParams(filterParams, pageRequest, null);
System.out.println("THIS IS MY RESULT: " + result);
Assertions.assertEquals(1, result.userRecords().size());
…
```

Comment: Where is bean definition of `org.companyname.enterpriseteam.demo.anonymizer.DAnonymizer`? Is this class annotated with `@Component` (or other bean creation annotations)? Or is it defined in some other configuration file? If none of the above, try to defining it's bean.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The bean definition is in a different package in a different repo. It basically resides in a shared library that our team uses, but it is not a bean. Should I create a config file for it in my current repo? Because I am not sure if DAnonymizer needs to be annotated as a bean since its worked fine with other implementations. We try not to modify that shared library too often, unless absolutely necessary. I feel like I am missing something simple because im new to Spring Boot.

Comment: Its important to add, we use artifactory to manage packages.

Comment: Yes, you need to define bean of `DAnonymizer` in your `@Configuration` class if it's not already a bean. You don't need to annotate DAnonymizer as bean. Only defining bean in config file should work. I will post sample code as answer

Answer (score 0):

Define bean of `DAnonymizer` in config class like below

```
@Configuration
public class DAnonymizerConfig {
  
  @Bean
  public DAnonymizer dAnonymizer() {
     return new DAnonymizer();//considering DAnonymizer has default constructor
  }

}
```

Comment: DemoAnonymizer is abstract so it doesnt have a default constructor. What would be a workaround? Thank you!

Comment: There should be some implementation of `DAnonymizer` which implements `getAnonymizedUserInfoForOrg` method. You can instantiate that class in bean. If not, you can create one and implement getAnonymizedUserInfoForOrg method(if DAnonymizer already has getAnonymizedUserInfoForOrg implementation, you can create empty class which extents DAnonymizer)